# Delete records in Access using SQL with conditions

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in access which has several columns. In some cases the first and second column match another record, but the last column has a different value for each record. I want to write an SQL code that goes through the table, and deletes one of the duplicates ONLY if the last row has a particular value.

I am new to VBA and SQL and such but I need them for my job.

I am decently experienced with python but the syntax is nowhere near similar, just the overall idea.

I know this should be a really simple thing to do and should only take up a few lines if that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have this question tagged `mysql` when it's about Access, not MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE 
  lastRow = 'particularValue' AND 
  (
  col1 IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, count(*)
    FROM yourTable
    HAVING count(*) > 1 )
  OR
  col2 IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT col2, count(*)
    FROM yourTable
    HAVING count(*) > 1 )
  )
```

Untested code. I'm sure you can work it out. Keep in mind to post your final solution.